# How to get json from webview in android

Tags: android, json, android-webview

I am trying to get a json data from url but its authenticated so i m hitting that url from webview.
On the webview , after i enter the username and password it returns the json.
I want to use that json in my program. I m unable to retrieve it
Is there is any way to get that data

Answer (score 0):

you simpy can not in this way. The backend has to provide a way to let you perform the authentication. Every time you perform an http request that requires authentication, you have to prove the fact you have performed authentication. For instance if the authentication was successful the server could return a token that you will provide every time you request the json.